# preg_match does not match html attribute on changing its order

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to match some xml tag with regular expression
here is my php code

```
   $pattern = '#<xt:tag_name *(type\="(.+?)")? *(detail\="(.+?)")? ?/>#ui';
   $str = '<xt:tag_name type="1" detail="2" />';
   preg_replace($pattern,"type: $1, detail: $4",$str);
   preg_match($pattern,$str,$m);
   print_r($m);
```

and i am getting expected result

```
Array
(
    [0] => <xt:tag_name type="1" detail="2" />
    [1] => type="1"
    [2] => 1
    [3] => detail="2"
    [4] => 2
)
```

but when i am changing the order of attributes

```
<xt:tag_name detail="2" type="1" />
```

matches gets failed

Comment: Did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ?

Comment: Suely your pattern shows that `type` occurs before `detail` so if you swap them around, you shouldn't expect the string to match?

Comment: **1)** You don't need to escape `=` **2)** the preg_replace line is useless, remove it **3)** use `|` to alternate patterns.

Comment: why are you parsing xml with regular expressions? If you need something that's not memory intensive, `XMLReader` may be a good option.

Comment: i am writing some complex application ex. <xt:file_list src="/folder_name" type="1" detail="2" /> will be replaced with all file and folder in folder_name

Comment: Well, complex applications can use a proper xml parser even more ;) Trying to parse xml with regex is just a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

This regex will capture the attributes `type` and `detail` regardless of the attribute order, providing they are inside the `xt:tag_name` tag.

`<xt:tag_name\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?!\>).)*\s\btype=(["'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1)(?=(?:(?!\>).)*\s\bdetail=(["'])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3)(?:(?!\>).)*\>`

[image]

## Expanded Description

- `<xt:tag_name\b` validates the tag name
- `(?=\s)` ensures there is a space after tag name
- `(?=` lookahead 1 for the `type`. By using a lookahead you can capture the attributes in any order.

  - `(?:(?!\>).)*` move through tag one character at a time and prevent the regex engine from exiting this tag until you reach
  - `\s\btype=` the attribute `type`
  - `(["'])` capture the open quote, this will be used later to match the proper close tag
  - `((?:(?!\1).)*)` capture all characters inside the quotes, but not including the same type of encapsulating quote
  - `\1` match the close quote
  - `)` close the lookahead for `type`
- `(?=(?:(?!\>).)*\s\bdetail=(["'])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3)` does the exact same thing for attribute named `detail` as was done for `type`
- `(?:(?!\>).)*` match all characters until
- `\>` the end of the tag

## Groups

Group 0 will have the entire tag from the open to close bracket

1. will have the open quote around the `type` value, this allows the regex to correctly match the close quote
2. will have the value from attribute `type`
3. will have the open quote around the `detail` value, this allows the regex to correctly match the close quote
4. will have the value from attribute `detail`

## PHP Code Example:

Input string

```
<xt:tag_name UselessAttribute="some dumb string" type="1" detail="2" /><xt:tag_name detail="Things 'Punk' Loves" MoreUselessAttributes="1231" type="kittens" />
```

Code

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/<xt:tag_name\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?!\>).)*\s\btype=(["\'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1)(?=(?:(?!\>).)*\s\bdetail=(["\'])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3)(?:(?!\>).)*\>/ims',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

Matches

```
$matches Array:
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <xt:tag_name UselessAttribute="some dumb string" type="1" detail="2" />
        [1] => <xt:tag_name detail="Things 'Punk' Loves" MoreUselessAttributes="1231" type="kittens" />
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "
        [1] => "
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => kittens
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "
        [1] => "
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Things 'Punk' Loves
    )
)
```

Comment: not the first time I saw you put regex images. What software are you using?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.